# Randomize, choose random numbers from 1 to 6, but not 0

Tags: delphi, random, numbers

I'd like to make 2 dices, but I don't want it to choose 0, this is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var x1,x2:integer; text1,text2:string;
begin
randomize;
x1:=random(7);
x2:=random(7);

text1:=inttostr(x1);
text2:=inttostr(x2);

label1.Caption:=text1;
label2.Caption:=text2;

end;
end.
```

What should I do to make it choose from 1 to 6, without including 0?

Comment: No need to keep calling Randomize. Call it once at startup.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: even stronger: calling randomize more than once messes up (restarts) the pseudo random number generator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
x1:=random(6) + 1;
```

should do the trick, it will never return zero now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Math.RandomRange):

```
uses Math;

begin
  x1 := RandomRange(1, 7);
```

(Which does internally exactly the same as [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309460/757830)...)